# Django: NOT Null constraint failed for SQLIte

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite

Below are my models. I am keep getting error when running `python manage.py migrate`

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: app_project.description
```

Models given below:

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.

class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True, default='')
    progress = models.FloatField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Task(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    severity = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    open_date = models.DateTimeField()
    close_date = models.DateTimeField()
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I am on Django 1.10

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

```
description = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True, default='')
```

in order to allow nullable values inside the db.

See the difference between null and blank [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#null) and [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/07/25/django-tip-8-blank-or-null.html).